# error when using exp build : [exp] API Response Error: Cannot convert `undefined` with r.expr()

Tags: exponentjs

This error appeared while using exponent CLI to build an standalone (shell) app:

```
[exp] API Response Error: Cannot convert `undefined` with r.expr() in:
r.db("prod").table("credentials").getAll(undefined, {
                                         ^^^^^^^^^  ^
    index: "username"
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are logged in through exponent CLI via

```
exp login
```

note that being logged in exponent XDE does not neccessarily mean you are logged in exponent CLI